# Write and read html form to textfile javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

i have write read and write html form to textfile in vb. i new in javascript, can anyone guide me how to covert these code to javascript? Below javascript is what i try to covert but the code is not working. Please correct me. Thank you.

vb.net code

```
    Dim filename As String = "C:\Users\Kit\test.txt"
    If System.IO.File.Exists(filename) = True Then
        Dim objwriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filename)
        objwriter.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
        objwriter.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text)
        objwriter.WriteLine(TextBox3.Text)
        objwriter.Close()
        MsgBox("Text written to file")
    Else
        File.Create("C:\Users\Kit\test.txt").Dispose()
        Dim objwriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filename)
        objwriter.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
        objwriter.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text)
        objwriter.WriteLine(TextBox3.Text)
        objwriter.Close()
        MsgBox("Text written to file")
    End If


    Dim filename As String = "C:\Users\Kit\test.txt"
    If System.IO.File.Exists(filename) = True Then
        Dim objreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(filename)
        TextBox1.Text = objreader.ReadLine
        TextBox2.Text = objreader.ReadLine
        TextBox3.Text = objreader.ReadLine
        objreader.Close()
        MsgBox("Text written to file")
    Else
        MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
    End If
```

Javascript

```
 function writefile()
 {  If (System.IO.File.Exists(filename)) = True Then
 {
    var objwritter = new StreamWritter("C:\Users\Kit\test.txt")
    objwriter.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text);
    objwriter.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text);
    objwriter.WriteLine(TextBox3.Text);
    objwritter.Close();
    MsgBox("Text written to file")
}       
Else
{
    File.Create("C:\Users\Kit\test.txt").Dispose()
    Dim objwriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filename)
    objwriter.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text);
    objwriter.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text);
    objwriter.WriteLine(TextBox3.Text);
    objwriter.Close();
    MsgBox("Text written to file")
}
End If
}

function readfile()
{
objread = new StreamReader("C:\Users\Kit\test.txt");
objread.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
objread.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text)
objread.WriteLine(TextBox3.Text)
objread.Close() 
}
```

Comment: So if I understood correctly, you're trying to convert your VB.NET code to JavaScript? I see you are use TextBoxes, so I'll guess you use WindowsForms? Why do you want to use JavaScript to do this exactly? You can only use JavaScript with WindowsForms if you're using a WebControl. Could you clear it up a little for me?

Comment: Yes. I trying to convert vb.net to JavaScript. I create using window form. Actually is use for save all the information to text file when the application disconnect and click the button retrieve back all the information. The text file will save in client pc.

Comment: Do you have a WebBrowser control in your application? If not, I'm not sure why you would need JavaScript to do that and I don't even think it's possible.

Comment: I not using Web Browser control. Do you have any suggestion to do that?

Comment: I would suggest to keep your vb.net code, you can't use JavaScript. Can you explain briefly what's your application and what you're trying to achieve?